expo-file-system not working properly with Expo SDK 51
In my project I want to download a pdf from our inside server. To this point we used expo-file-system and it worked seamlessly but after updating the expo sdk to 51, I constantly get 403 forbidden.
I am using the .createDownloadResumable and .downloadAsync methods of the expo-file-system.
const fileURL = URL_to_our_pdf_download_link;
const filePath = path_of_the_file.pdf;
const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
fileURL,
filePath,
);
try {
const { uri: fileUri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(fileURL, filePath);
const fileContent = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, { encoding:            FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 });
console.log('File content:', fileContent);
} catch (e) {
  setPdfIsLoading(false);
  showSnack({ message: e });
}

